# Django admin: displaying computed property when viewing a single item

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin

I store compressed strings in the database. I would like to see the actual string when in Django Admin. Since the strings are very long, I don't want them to appear in the list view, but only when viewing a single item (row). So, I can define:

```py
@property
def short_my_field(self):
    return pickle.loads(brotli.decompress(self.my_field))[:80]

@property
def original_my_field(self):
    return pickle.loads(brotli.decompress(self.my_field))
```

I will then put `short_my_field` into `list_display`. But how do I cause `original_my_field` to display when viewing a single item?

Comment: What do you mean by *"viewing a single item"*? Are you referring to "list view" or "detail-view"? IMHO, simple image would be better

Comment: @JPG I understand that the list view shows a whole page of rows. So, I guess I am referring to the change view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a [**`readonly_fields`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) as below,

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ("anything_you_want",)
    fields = ("field_1", "anything_you_want")

    def anything_you_want(self, obj):
        return obj.original_my_field
```

Comment: How does making the field read-only help for what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: I works, but an explanation would be appreciated...

Comment: I hope the reference to the official doc explains it very well - *"A read-only field can not only display data from a model’s field, it can also display the output of a model’s method or a method of the ModelAdmin class itself."*